# Wpf client of TipCalc Tutorial not working

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I tried to follow the tipcalc tutorial on mvvmcross.com. All clients work except the Wpf client. I would like to get it running as it promises to be a performat debugging platform for Mvx together with XForms.

I followed the tutorial using the nupkgs MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Wpf (instead of the MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf given there which I suppose is wrong there). But when I try to start it, I get the following exception:

**"Could not find a setup class for application"**, the innermost stacktrace being:

```
bei MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetupExtensions.CreateSetup[TSetup]() in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Core\MvxSetupExtensions.cs:Zeile 41.
   bei MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup.Instance() in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Core\MvxSetup.cs:Zeile 48.
   bei MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetupSingleton.CreateSetup() in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Core\MvxSetupSingleton.cs:Zeile 158.
```

Actually the Application class is derived from MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Views.MvxApplication but the RegisterSetup method is not called during startup.

My supposition is that the framework is not yet ready to get Wpf running together with Xamarin.Forms. Am I correct here?
If not: **I would appreciate any hint or link to a running code sample Mvx/XForms/Wpf**

Comment: You should install both `MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Wpf` and `MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf`

Comment: I did - the followind packages are installed (all for .Netv4.7.2):
MvvmCross, MvvmCross.Forms, MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Wpf, MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf (all v6.2.3), 
OpenTK (v2.0.0), OpenTK.GLControl (v1.1.2349.61993), 
System.Console (v4.3.1), 
Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Wpf  (v3.4.0.1009999)

I can share the project if this helps. Maybe I did something wrong, but I really could not find any sample out there

Comment: I got it working. The problem was, that in App.Xaml of the Wpf project I specified the App class as X.WPF.App, and in App.xaml.cs it is X.Wpf.App. I'm wondering anyway why there was no warning during build (which I'm sure I would have gotten in VS2017, and I'm using VS2019)